# How do I change the path used by the Gnome Command Line applet?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, path, gnome-panel

For my shell, I know that I have to modify `.bashrc` to add my `~/bin` directory to the command path, but how do I get the Gnome Command Line applet to use that as a program location too?

<sup>I'm using v2.13.0.1 if that makes a difference</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `PATH` or any other environment variable in `~/.bashrc`. `.bashrc` is a shell configuration file, you should use it only for shell configuration (such as prompts and aliases). Environment variables apply to all applications, so set them in your session initialization file. All methods for non-graphical logins (text mode console or remote login) read **`~/.profile`** (unless you have an exotic shell); for graphical logins, `~/.profile` is often read, but that depends on your distribution, display manager and desktop environment. Your desktop environment (Gnome) may have a way to set environment variables when you log in, too.

Comment: Unfortunately a quick test, adding `export PATH=/scratch/bin:$PATH` to my `.profile` and then logging out/back in doesn't allow me to run anything in `/scratch/bin` from the Gnome Command Line applet, so Gnome must not honour `.profile` on my system.